# Trying to wire ceiling fan with separate light/fan switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

Trying to wire a manual ceiling fan/light combo.

Image 1 is the current light switch:  [image: Original light switch] Not sure why there are 2 black wires.  There is only 1 black wire coming from the ceiling, but it is connected with a red wire... Both hot I assume? See figure 3...

Image 3 is the new fan/light fixture.  Blue and black wires on the right are fan and light as I recall. The black wire is connected with a red wire.  Both hot?[image]

Image 2 is the new dual single pole switch to separate the fan and light power.[image]

Can anyone tell me how or if this can be wired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The black wire going through the "hole" in the back of the switch, the always hot, should be connected to the black screws.If there is a metal link between the two black screws, then only one connection is needed. If no link, then you need to jump the two black screws. The black wire on the screw on the old switch and the red wire on the old switch get connected to the two screws, silver or brass, on the new switch. The ground wire gets connected to the green screw.

Comment: Yep, that was it!  Thank you so much, I would not have figured that out on my own!

Comment: @abaker  If an answer solves your problem, you can upvote or check mark it so other's will know it's good.